# Vertically center image if height less than parent.height, else limit height to 100%

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using html5-fullscreen mode with a full-screen parent div, in which I want to vertically center an image, but only if the image is smaller then the parent div (ie. the screen size). I also want to limit the image to `max-height` = 100% of parent, to avoid zooming in if the image is larger than the screen.

I can center the image with two divs (one `display:table`, and the other `display:table-cell`), but I cannot at the same time set the image `max-height` to not be more than the parent div. I can do the latter by using `position:absolute; max-height:100%;` but then the centering doesn't work on smaller images.

Example markup:

```
<div id="fullscreen-container">
    <div id="fullscreen-img-wrapper">
        <img id="fullscreen-img" src="/images/test-6000x4000.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how that can be accomplished are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post some code so we can tell what you have already?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#fullscreen-img-wrapper { display: table-cell;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%; }
#fullscreen-img { width:100%; }
</style>

<div id="fullscreen-container">
    <div id="fullscreen-img-wrapper">
        <img id="fullscreen-img" src="/images/test-6000x4000.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It just made the image 100% it's real size (eg 6000px wide).